# vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq 5.4 requires illuminate/support 5.4.*

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, laravel-5.6

I am updating my `laravel` from `5.5.*` to `5.6.0`. Upon composer install after updating my `composer.json` to require `laravel 5.6.0` it is showing this:

> vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq 5.4 requires
> illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36],
> illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
> v5.4.36, v5.4.9].

And:

> vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq 5.4 requires
> illuminate/database 5.4.* -> satisfiable by
> laravel/framework[v5.4.36], illuminate/database[v5.4.0, v5.4.13,
> v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].

What version of `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` is compatible with `l5.6.0`? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
  "description": "application.",
  "keywords": [
    "key"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/skmedia/laravel-extended-validator"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/skmedia/laravel-commentable"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/skmedia/commander"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/skmedia/laravel-fractal"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "<url>"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/Phi-os/eloquent-meta"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/Phi-os/passport"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "<url>"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "2.*",
    "crhayes/validation": "dev-laravel5",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.3",
    "nanigans/single-table-inheritance": "0.8.8",
    "laracasts/commander": "dev-master",
    "keen-io/keen-io": "~2.5",
    "vierbergenlars/php-semver": "~3.0",
    "beberlei/assert": "~2.3",
    "league/csv": "~7.0",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "~3.1",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "^2.0",
    "league/fractal": "0.17.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "nicmart/string-template": "~0.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "predis/predis": "~1.0",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.1",
    "hackzilla/password-generator": "^1.1",
    "phoenix/eloquent-meta": "dev-l54",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1",
    "lanz/laravel-commentable": "dev-master",
    "league/period": "^3.1",
    "moneyphp/money": "^3.0",
    "dingo/api": "2.0.0",
    "rtconner/laravel-tagging": "~2.2",
    "neomerx/json-api": "^0.8.8",
    "box/spout": "^2.7",
    "graham-campbell/throttle": "^5.3",
    "laravel/passport": "dev-uuid53",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
    "klamote/brittle": "~0.0.3-alpha",
    "neitanod/forceutf8": "~2.0",
    "teampickr/php-google-maps-distance-matrix": "^0.5.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq": "5.4"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4",
    "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "1.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database",
      "tests/integration/database/seeds/shared",
      "tests/integration/database/seeds/tests"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Phirater\\": "app/",
      "PhiraterTest\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": ["bootstrap/helpers.php"]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: You know, laravel 5.6.0 is still quite an old version. Are you planning to update further?

Comment: @WesleySmith yes, I am updating but one step at a time. Also I have updated the question. Kindly look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation [here](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) it seems that version 7.0 is compatible with laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a 7.0 version I think.